# GitHub including other people's commits in my pull request

Tags: git

I committed my changes onto my repository and while creating a pull request, I can see other people's committed changes into my pull request as well. Under the diffs tab, it shows other people's files too. I just want my files in my pull request, how can I achieve that?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you would see other people commits when creating a PR, unless you pushed your fixes onto a common branch (like master).

You should:

- create a new branch locally (`git switch -c newBranchForFix <oldSHA1>`) from a known starting point (before your current commits)
- reports your commits onto that new branch (for instance with [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick))
- push that new branch
- make your PR from said new branch.

Answer (score 1):

This is common issue when you pull changes onto your branch and may be some other reasons. Approach which I always take and work **99.99%** time is given below.

Suppose you are working on a `feature branch` from 3 days. Definitely it is outdated.

simple way you you do the `rebase`.

you have created a feture branch from commit ***`E`*** on master

```
      A---B---C topic
     /
D---E---F---G master
```

Run either of following commands

```
git rebase master
git rebase master topic
```

Result would be

```
              A'--B'--C' topic
             /
D---E---F---G master
```

but my favorite way is given below.

use below mentioned command, this is hassle free.

```
 1. git fetch 
 2. git stash
 3. git branch -d master (this is just locally and will remove old merger in commits)
 4. git checkout master (this way you will get a fresh master branch here)
 5. git checkout -b new-feture-branch 
 6. git stash pop
```

you have a clean scope now. But you decide which way you want to go.

Also if you you want to use `alias` to shorten above mentioned commands, Let me know I will update answer.